# how to search all cells in sheet6 range "b2:b" for a matching value in sheet2 range m7:m1000

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search, range

How can i change the id into a range? for each cell in range search finalrow.

```
Dim id As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet6.Range("B2:B8")
id = Sheet6.Range("A2").Value
finalrow = Sheet2.Range("C6000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    For Each cell In rng
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) = id Then
    'MsgBox "FOUND IT"
    Sheet6.Range("D2").Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
Next
    Next i
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question using this guidelines [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Put more info about:

Comment: What you want: to set the id (string) into a Range data type? Or you want to take the value inside id, and set a Range var?? Do you get any error??

Comment: This seems like a classic INDEX/MATCH question

Comment: RE 'classic Index prob;..Not sure if index will reference text address alone:(could use indirect within index though - also - outputs could be a little tricky to summarise due to potential 'Spill' effects  - at least when referencing / searching for contiguous groups of cells/target ranges)...

Answer (score 0):

### a) VB Code

Screenshot (b) refers:

---

```
Sub search_tool()
  i = 0
  For Each cell_1 In Range("b6", Range("b6").End(xlDown))
    target = cell_1.Value
   
    For Each cell_2 In Range(target).Cells
      i = i + 1
      Range("b16").Offset(i - 1).Value = cell_2.Value
      Range("c16").Offset(i - 1).Formula2R1C1 = target
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

---

### b) Screenshot

[image: Sample for reference to solution ifor this Q]

(google sheet, w/ VB code and other sheets - hidden, protected - see c - included [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eMqmWKMGMxnWHSvkFQCBx8rFlDPZKqc9w_YB0vMNUA/edit?usp=sharing))

### c) How it works

1. Inputs: Enter target cells you're searching for as regular text (yellow-shaded cells)
2. Include sheet names (hidden or otherwise) as shown in first and last inputs (B6, B10).  Note: password protected sheets and window structures won't inhibit/restrict functionality of this macro (only tested under basic restrictions - see section d for mor e inof/uncertainty
3. Untested: different workbooks (open/closed).
4. Outputs: populated upon executing macro (existing values will be overridden as required)
5. Alternative VB code for quick referencing/seeking cells:

---

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R6C5:R7C5"
```

---

### d) Other

(non-essential information, not directly related/requested in Q, but worth considering as required).

Testing hidden / protected sheets.  Basic criteria per following screenshots:

- Cells in sheet were locked (default, but check using right click | properties)
- Password protection was applied to sheet and structure before hiding 'Hidden' sheet.

[image]